# Wrapping <pre> tag - only partially working

Tags: html, css

From various SO answers and random web searches (e.g. https://www.sitepoint.com/everything-need-know-html-pre-element), it seems wrapping a long word in a `<pre>` tag using the CSS can be achieved with a combination of:

- [CSS white-space property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)
- [CSS overflow-wrap property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

Example CSS:

```
pre {
  /* Whitespace preserved. Text wraps when necessary, and on line breaks. */
  white-space: pre-wrap;

  /* normally unbreakable words may be broken at arbitrary points. */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This works, but only wraps one line. Pop over to https://jsonschema.net to see this problem in action.

`$id` properties can get long very quickly (do this quickly by adding a long **Root ID** and just submitting the *default* JSON).

[image]

Inspecting the DOM shows the correct CSS applied to the `<pre>` tag container:

[image]

The long string is wrapping, but only where a line break occurs. How can I ensure it wraps beyond one line?

Comment: Did you try word-wrap: break-word with specified width?

Comment: Yes, or try adding `word-break: break-all;` and see if that's what you want. See [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) and especially the **Note** where it compares it to `overflow-wrap`

Comment: @stephen-p `word-break: break-all;` did it! Ty.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Ima
ges and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: You are required to post a complete but minimal example of your problem markup or code here within your question that allows us to duplicate the issue: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit for this answer should go to [@stephen-p](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17300/stephen-p) since their comment resolved my issue. I'm only answering my own question because comments are easily missed:

> Yes, or try adding word-break: break-all; and see if that's what you
>   want. See word-break and especially the Note where it compares it to
>   overflow-wrap

So `word-break: break-all;` was all I needed.